# Frequent segmentation faults causing browser and/or system to freeze

Tags: kernel, nvidia, video, amd, segmentation-fault

I have been having issues for awhile with a new PC I built. I decided to go with Pop!_OS (didn't see a dedicated Pop!_OS forum so here I am) since it is supposed to support a lot engineering and data science related software. This PC has an AMD® Ryzen 9 7900x 12-core processor × 24  and an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 graphics card.

So, to the point, I have been monitoring `/var/log/kern.log` in the background have noticed that whenever my browser or program crashes it is likely associated with some segmentation fault.

Here is a non exhaustive list that have cause programs to stop:

`chrome[9700]: segfault at 2d9b0303031a ip 000056081a8321db sp 00007ffcb1ad3580 error 4 in chrome[56081916f000+a492000] likely on CPU 17 (core 5, socket 0)`

`ThreadPoolForeg[12433]: segfault at 43168001 ip 000056081ff5485d sp 00007f73631fbba0 error 4 in chrome[56081916f000+a492000] likely on CPU 20 (core 10, socket 0)`

`gnome-shell[3019]: segfault at e641f8bf ip 00007f297b1f66d8 sp 00007ffe52033c60 error 6 in libmutter-clutter-10.so.0.0.0[7f297b1e0000+91000] likely on CPU 11 (core 13, socket 0)`

`Isolated Web Co[5349]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f79f7e1e861 sp 00007ffce6a71a10 error 4 in libxul.so[7f79f40be000+5e78000] likely on CPU 22 (core 12, socket 0)`

`VirtualBoxVM[5863]: segfault at 10 ip 00007f8cfe6a3b41 sp 00007ffc0591a670 error 6 in libc.so.6[7f8cfe692000+12b000] likely on CPU 19 (core 9, socket 0)`

`ibus-daemon[3165]: segfault at 20c4 ip 00007f7b14f6269d sp 00007ffc3272dee0 error 4 in libgobject-2.0.so.0.7200.4[7f7b14f48000+33000] likely on CPU 19 (core 9, socket 0)`

I get Isolated Web faults most regularly when online and in a video call.

I really don't know where to start or how to narrow down the issue. I think I should focus on identifying the source of the segfaults first since they have been happening the whole time. Any advice or direction would be helpful.

---

*UPDATE*

I've investigated `sudo journalctl  -b 0` to review the latest boot and have pulled I believe all the errors.

```
Oct 05 08:31:32 pop-os kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP7.UP00.DP40.UP00.DP68], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230331/dswload2-162)
Oct 05 08:31:32 pop-os kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20230331/psobject-220)

Oct 05 08:31:32 pop-os kernel: hub 8-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)

Oct 05 08:31:33 pop-os /usr/bin/nvidia-powerd[1202]: No matching GPU found
Oct 05 08:31:33 pop-os /usr/bin/nvidia-powerd[1202]: Failed to initialize RM Client
Oct 05 08:31:33 pop-os systemd[1]: nvidia-powerd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 05 08:31:33 pop-os systemd[1]: nvidia-powerd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 05 08:31:33 pop-os systemd[1]: Failed to start nvidia-powerd service.

Oct 05 08:31:34 pop-os vboxdrv.sh[1979]: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what went wrong.
Oct 05 08:31:34 pop-os systemd[1]: vboxdrv.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 05 08:31:34 pop-os systemd[1]: vboxdrv.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 05 08:31:34 pop-os systemd[1]: Failed to start VirtualBox Linux kernel module.

Oct 05 08:31:35 pop-os gnome-session[2074]: gnome-session-binary[2074]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
Oct 05 08:31:35 pop-os gnome-session[2074]: gnome-session-binary[2074]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
Oct 05 08:31:35 pop-os gnome-session-binary[2074]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed

Oct 05 08:31:37 pop-os wpa_supplicant[1247]: bgscan simple: Failed to enable signal strength monitoring

Oct 05 08:40:40 pop-os systemd[3353]: app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dssh-3591.scope: Failed to add PIDs to scope's control group: No such process
Oct 05 08:40:40 pop-os systemd[3353]: app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dssh-3591.scope: Failed with result 'resources'.
Oct 05 08:40:40 pop-os systemd[3353]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.

Oct 05 08:40:42 pop-os gnome-shell[3601]: GNOME Shell started at Thu Oct 05 2023 08:40:41 GMT-0400 (EDT)
Oct 05 08:40:42 pop-os gnome-shell[3601]: Registering session with GDM
Oct 05 08:40:42 pop-os gsd-sharing[2148]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing: The connection is closed
Oct 05 08:40:42 pop-os gsd-rfkill[2159]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill: The connection is closed
Oct 05 08:40:42 pop-os gnome-session-binary[2074]: GLib-CRITICAL: g_hash_table_foreach_remove_or_steal: assertion 'version == hash_table->version' failed
```

Some others I noticed after a fresh boot.

```
Oct 05 22:22:49 pop-os kernel: FAT-fs (nvme0n1p1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
Oct 05 22:22:49 pop-os kernel: FAT-fs (nvme0n1p2): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.

Oct 05 22:22:49 pop-os kernel: nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
Oct 05 22:22:49 pop-os kernel: Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
Oct 05 22:22:49 pop-os kernel: nvidia: module license taints kernel.
```

---

*Update - Memtest86 Failures*

Well, I successfully ran the Memtest86 test suite and failures have been identified. Sounds like this is in fact a hardware issue.

[image]

It sounds like Memtest86 can identify whether hardware issues exist, but cannot pinpoint the which device is failing. Seems like 1 or both of my RAM sticks have issues.

> ***MemTest86 detected errors in my memory. Is there something wrong with my RAM?***

> Please be aware that not all errors reported by MemTest86 are due to bad memory. The test implicitly tests the CPU, L1 and L2 caches as well as the motherboard. It is impossible for the test to determine what causes the failure to occur. However, most failures will be due to a problem with memory module. When it is not, the only option is to replace parts until the failure is corrected.

I appreciate everyone's comments. At this point I am thinking I should rerun Memtest with one RAM stick in at a time? Also, are there similar tools I can use to test my CPU?

Lastly, I have had this PC only a couple months. If I am able to pinpoint the faulty hardware will I be able to have the OEM replace it, or am I just out of luck?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the `Possible missing firmware` for amdgpu warnings, not the issue (considering you use an nVidia GPU) - personally, I would suspect the nVidia drivers - can you specify which AMD cpu and which nVidia GPU you have

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX , your comment makes sense. I've updated the post to reflect the build: AMD® Ryzen 9 7900x 12-core processor × 24  and NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060

Comment: "Segmentation Fault" is Unix/Linux-speak for "illegal memory access", e.g. reference to location 0, or reference to unallocated memory. It can be caused by a missing shared library (run `ldd` on the binaries),  or really bad configuration of something you haven't mentioned,  or version skew in libraries or repositories, or possibly hardware faults. If PopOS! has `journalctl`, read `man journalctl`, and start with `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. If not look at the files in `/var/log/*`.

Comment: Thanks @waltinator , I've encountered segmentation faults when writing small c++ programs for a course I took not too long ago I have an idea of why these programs are crashing. Also, I read a little bit of the manual for `journalctl` and ran `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. I've updated the post with what I believe are notable errors from the log. I am currently reviewing how to use `ldd`.

Comment: No, missing libraries don’t cause segmentation faults. Widespread segmentation faults involving many different binaries typically indicate a hardware problem — have you tried checking your memory with [Memtest86+](https://memtest.org/) or a similar tool?

Comment: @StephenKitt - Thanks for the recommendation. I've updated the post with the Memtest resullts. It did find errors. I am now left with some other questions about handling hardware issues. See post.

Comment: This is no longer about Unix or Linux, it’s off-topic here so I’ll leave this as a comment. You can try running a memory check with only one stick to determine whether a single stick is faulty, yes. If that works, then you’ll know what to send back (two-month-old hardware should be covered by a warranty). If it doesn’t, the odds are still that it’s the memory that’s faulty; you can try either sending the pair of sticks back, or find a pair to borrow for further tests. Beyond that, the strategy is still swapping, but it gets more expensive...

Comment: Removed one of the RAM sticks and it passed. Thanks for the help @StephenKitt